# If Condition Is Met, Move To Different View...

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can I push to a different view if a condition is met? Basically, I need to go to a different view controller`SetupViewController` on the very first load (which is something that is logged in NSUserDefaults).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact method will depend on whether you're using IB or building your UI programmatically. Can you give me some implementation details?

If you're working through IB, you'll have to make sure the UIWindow.xib doesn't point to a view controller, and you'll have to set it on start. Basically, you're going to set the UIWindow's rootViewController on start of your app.